# Add a firefox webextension when installing the native host application

Tags: firefox, registry, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created a firefox webextension that communicates with a native host application. I also have created an installer for the native host application. Is there a way to enable the extension on the firefox when installing the native host application, via windows registry maybe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this anymore (officially). For a good reason. My suggestion: Open the URL to your extension with the users default browser and let the user click the install button manually.

Comment: Are you asking about actually forcing it to be enabled (which if done without user consent might get your add-on removed from AMO), or installing it with the user given the option to enable it the next time Firefox is runs (by profile)? Do you have administrator/root privileges when installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install using the registry, as documented at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry

For general instructions that include platforms other than Windows see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions